# SQL запрос

Tags: sql

Нужно создать запрос, берущий максимальное значения поля iq для каждого юзера (user_id).. у каждого пользователя таких полей может быть несколько. насколько я понимаю это вложенный запрос. пробовал по разному не канает. подскажи чего..
Писал так :
    SELECT th.user_id, MAX(th.iq) FROM tests_iq_history th GROUP BY th.user_id ORDER BY th.iq DESC

но выдает немного не те значения

Comment: Обычный запрос с группировкой (`GROUP BY`) по `user_id` и агрегацией (`MAX(...)`) по полю `iq`.

Comment: @Broouzer King, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: GROUP BY
 работает не  совсем правильно. незнаю уж почему, не все значения в списке для пользователя максимальные...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил добавлением AS
SELECT th.user_id,
 MAX(th.iq) as usrMAX_iq
 FROM tests_iq_history th

GROUP BY th.user_id
 ORDER BY usrMAX_iq DESC